# JPA no-op Predicate possible?

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

It is possible to create a no-op `Predicate` with JPA? aka an "empty" predicate, meaning one that doesn't render into anything in the generated SQL.

I've tested  [`CriteriaBuilder.conjunction()`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/3.1/apidocs/jakarta.persistence/jakarta/persistence/criteria/criteriabuilder#conjunction()) which does the job but at least with Hibernate it renders into a SQL `WHERE` clause like this : `1 = 1` instead of rendering into nothing. So not quite what I want.

### Updated answer

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77388018/1504556) suggests to simply return `null` (thank you!). Since I'm working with Spring's [Specification](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/reference/jpa/specifications.html) abstraction (did I mention that?) returning `null` for Predicate will actually work nicely.

So we have something like:

```java
public static Specification<Car> myClause(String matchVal) {
    return (root, query, builder) -> {
   
        if (matchVal == null) {
            return null;
        }

        // Construct Predicate
        ...

    };
}
```

When aggregated Specification are later composed/combined, the ones that produce a `null` Predicate will be ignored. Voila.

Comment: What do you mean by "empty" predicate? Either you should build a predicate or you shouldn't, you can't use an if statement when you build a Where clause?

Comment: @viking: It was for Predicates that are to be conditionally ignored. As you can see from the updated posting this is possible simply by returning a `null` Predicate.

Comment: `builder.and()` produces `1=1`, `builder.or()` produces `1=0`, any attempt to build some kind of reliable logic around nulls is doomed to failure.

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov. I would normally agree. However, I'm using Spring [Specification](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/reference/jpa/specifications.html), not just bare-bone JPA. This changes the score a bit. It is fully documented that [toPredicate()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/domain/Specification.html#toPredicate(jakarta.persistence.criteria.Root,jakarta.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery,jakarta.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder)) is allowed to return `null`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you dont want to add any condition to query. Let's try to `return null` instead of return conjunction.